# check if a specific column value exists corresponding to another column and return its id in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit

There is a table say t1

| id | subject | day | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 211 | maths | mon | asmnt |
| 222 | maths | tue | asmnt |
| 223 | science | mon | test |
| 224 | science | tue | asmt |
| 225 | science | wed | insp |
| 226 | computers | mon | asmt |
| 227 | maths | mon | test |
| 228 | computers | mon | insp |
| 229 | computers | thr | asmnt |
| 230 | computers | fri | asmnt |

now i want a **SQL query** to find id subject which **never** had `event = test` on any day and return **its first event**
so output is

| id | subject | day | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 226 | computers | mon | asmt |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `DISTINCT ON` here along with exists logic:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (subject) *
FROM t1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 b
                  WHERE b.subject = a.subject AND b.event = 'test')
ORDER BY subject, id;
```

Answer (score 0):

use not exists and row_number() but for postgre it is wise to use distinct on which already given a answer by @Tim

```
 with cte as 
(  select t1.*,
  row_number()over(partition by subject order by id)
  rn from table_name t1
    where not exists ( select 1 from table_name t2 where t1.subject=t2.subject
                                and t2.event='test')  
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `NOT IN` or `not exists` to exclude subjects for which `event='test'` exists. Using order Limit 1 with order by id will select one row with lowest value of id column.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table t1 (id    int,subject varchar(20), day varchar(20), event varchar(20));

 insert into t1 values(211, 'maths' ,'mon', 'asmnt');
 insert into t1 values(222, 'maths' ,'tue', 'asmnt');
 insert into t1 values(223, 'science'   ,'mon', 'test');
 insert into t1 values(224, 'science'   ,'tue', 'asmt');
 insert into t1 values(225, 'science'   ,'wed', 'insp');
 insert into t1 values(226, 'computers' ,'mon', 'asmt');
 insert into t1 values(227, 'maths' ,'mon', 'test');
 insert into t1 values(228, 'computers' ,'mon', 'insp');
 insert into t1 values(229, 'computers' ,'thr', 'asmnt');
 insert into t1 values(230, 'computers' ,'fri', 'asmnt');
```

Query1: using `NOT IN`

```
 SELECT * FROM t1 a
 WHERE subject not in
                 (
                   SELECT subject FROM t1 b WHERE b.event='test'
                 )
 order by id
 Limit 1
```

Output:

| id | subject | day | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 226 | computers | mon | asmt |

Query2: using `not exists`

```
 SELECT * FROM t1 a
 WHERE not exists 
                 (
                   SELECT 1 FROM t1 b WHERE b.event='test' and a.subject=b.subject
                 )
 order by id
 Limit 1
```

Output:

| id | subject | day | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 226 | computers | mon | asmt |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8336ec375e63d2aa05513e368e665753)*

Comment: if there are more then one subject with no event = test then this query will fail as it will always return one row due to limit 1 and if you remove limit 1 it wont give us correct response